# MySQL select data from last week

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to select all the data from last week? Between Monday to Friday, assuming that today is a Monday. I actually don't have a datetime format column.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE WEEKDAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 
AND YEARWEEK( date_added2 ) = YEARWEEK( CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND deleted='n';
```

And this is my table, table logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? you can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3989b1/3/0

```
SELECT *
FROM logs,
  (SELECT (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) + 1 ) % 7 DAY) AS sun_day) t1
WHERE
    logs.date_added2 BETWEEN t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 6 DAY 
        AND t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
```

**How it works**

folling query returns sunday of week

```
SELECT '2014-01-09' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2014-01-09') + 1 ) % 7 DAY;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| '2014-01-09' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2014-01-09') + 1 ) % 7 DAY |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-05                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT '2014-01-10' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2014-01-10') + 1 ) % 7 DAY;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| '2014-01-10' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2014-01-10') + 1 ) % 7 DAY |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-05                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so, `t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 6` holds monday of previous week, and `t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 2 DAY` for friday of previous week.

```
mysql> SELECT @sunday := (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) + 1 ) % 7 DAY) AS sunday;
+------------+
| sunday     |
+------------+
| 2014-01-05 |
+------------+

mysql> SELECT @sunday - INTERVAL 6 DAY, @sunday -  INTERVAL 2 DAY;
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| @sunday - INTERVAL 6 DAY | @sunday -  INTERVAL 2 DAY |
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2013-12-30               | 2014-01-03                |
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
```

So, `logs.date_added2 BETWEEN t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND t1.sun_day - INTERVAL 2 DAY` would find logs from monday to friday.